# Return dropdown selection - php/sql

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I'm populating a drop down box using values from sql, but I'm having trouble getting the drop down to return a value. After much searching, I've come across many ideas but none have worked. Any help is appreciated.

The relevant code I have is shown below. Please be gentle, this is fairly new to me!

Thanks.

```
<?php

echo "<form action=\"theForm\" method=\"GET\">";
echo "<select name=\"courier_select\">";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(courier) AS courier FROM reviews ORDER BY courier ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ echo "<option value=\"courier\">" . $row['courier'] . "</option>"; }

echo "</select>";
echo "</form>";

echo $_GET['theForm'];

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're explicitly setting the `value` attribute of `<option>` element to `courier`, the value of `courier_select` will always be that.

You need to set the value to be that pulled from the database, as follows:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) )
{ 
    echo '<option value="'.$row['courier'].'">'.$row['courier'].'</option>'; 
}
```

Now, when you try to access the `<select>` element's value (using either `$_GET['courier_select']` or `$_POST['courier_select']` depending upon the form's method), you'll get the selected value.

It's worth noting that the `mysql_*` family of functions is now deprecated, and you should investigate the use of either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) before putting this code into production.

---

Also, it appears that you lack a basic grasp of how `<form>` elements work. The form needs to be submitted, and the `action` attribute defines where the submitted data should be sent. You will need to update the `action` attribute to be a page on your website that handles the form. Alternatively, remove the attribute to have the form submit to the page it resides on.

Once the form has been submitted (you'll need a `<button type="submit">Submit</button>` for that), you can then access the form's data using the `$_GET` superglobal (because you're specifying a `method` of `GET`), or `$_POST` if you used the `POST` method.

Both `$_GET` and `$_POST` are arrays, and their keys refer to the form elements' names. So in order to get the value of the `courier_select` selectbox, you can use:

```
$_GET['courier_select'];
```

Comment: Ben, thanks very much. You put me on the right track and prompted me to learn more about the form element; it's now working.